# GROUP BY only when column is not null/empty

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I get this error due to the GROUP BY statement.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN a.link !='' THEN a.filimo_link END

I want to only group by when `a.link` is not empty.  So don't group empty.  What is wrong with my query

```
SELECT b.name as name, a.title, a.id
FROM (`all_media` a)
LEFT JOIN `admins` b ON `b`.`id`=`user_id`
WHERE `a`.`approved` =  0
GROUP BY `a`.`link` CASE WHEN a.link !='' THEN a.link END
ORDER BY `a`.`filename`
```

Comment: You want to group by an item which is not selected. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

There sholud be value for group by in else part.or use other column in combination with group by.

```
SELECT b.name as name, a.title, a.id
FROM (`all_media` a)
LEFT JOIN `admins` b ON `b`.`id`=`user_id`
WHERE `a`.`approved` =  0
GROUP BY `a`.`link` CASE WHEN a.link IS NOT NULL THEN a.link ELSE '' END
ORDER BY `a`.`filename`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
SELECT b.name as name, a.title, a.id
FROM (`all_media` a)
LEFT JOIN `admins` b ON `b`.`id`=`user_id`
WHERE `a`.`approved` =  0
GROUP BY `a`.`link` HAVING a.link IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `a`.`filename'
```

Hope it helps.